# Access Value From Object

Tags: php

I got the following results in a object after I did a var_dump on that object, how can I access the individual elements and put them into a variable?

I tried:

```
$content["ID"];
$content->ID;
```

but no result :-(

```
  ["ID"]=>
  string(5) "31655"
  ["Reference"]=>
  string(7) "1899801"
  ["FullName"]=>
  string(18) "Lennie De Villiers"
  ["Username"]=>
  string(12) "lenniedg2000"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it on your end and see output

```
 echo $content->ID;
 $var=$content->ID;
 echo $var;
```

Just take a look here I created an example

http://codepad.org/KMDNCto3

Comment: object(SimpleXMLElement)#15 (17) { ["ID"]=> string(5) "31655" ["Reference"]=> string(7) "1899801" ["FullName"]=> string(18) "Lennie De Villiers" ["Username"]=> string(12) "lenniedg2000"    Is what am getting back.